# Ignore a element on the loop if the string is different

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show the products on a page when the user do a search. I need to show 15 products on the page, and I have a filter to show only the category that the user is researching. When the user searches for something, the page don't show the products that don't match the search, which is good, but it is somehow still getting them, because the page don't show the 15 products that it should be showing. I need that the "if" completely ignore the results that don't match. I'm sorry if is not explained very well, I can explain more if someone need.

```
while(have_posts()):
            the_post();

if(isset($_GET['select-option']) && $_GET['select-option'] == 'search-albuns' && $categories[0] == 'Álbum') {
```

The problem is on `$categories[0] == 'Álbum'`, if the category is different, the "if" still gets it.

Comment: Where exactly does the `$categories` variable come from and get populated? Why are you always testing index 0 of it? Should you not be testing a different index each time? It's a little unclear due to the lack of context. We don't know anything about these products etc or how it relates to the categories data or the user's search criteria.

Comment: I don't have time to write up a deep explanation with a sample, but you need to modify the WordPress query _before_ it hits the database. Check out this [article](https://presscustomizr.com/snippet/three-techniques-to-alter-the-query-in-wordpress/), specifically about the `pre_get_posts` hook. Inside of there you'd apply your `if` logic along with probably a [meta query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72126/12496).

Comment: Sorry for be replying just now, I got stuck with some other things. But @ChrisHaas suggestion worked! The answer was pre_get_posts, after search for it I finally found the right way of use pre_get_posts in my case. Thanks a lot for your suggestion, it really helped.